# The meaning of "have long said"

Tags: phrase-usage

I read a news article. I don't quite understand "have long said". Does it mean the prosecutors had a long speech or they said it a long time ago?

> But prosecutors **have long said** they believe he killed many more people, last year putting the figure at 43 at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [long](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/long) : adverb
>
> ```
> 1 For a long time.
>
> ‘we hadn't known them long’
> ‘an experience they will long remember’
> ‘his long-awaited Grand Prix debut’
> ```

It means that the prosecutors have said it for a long time.

Comment: It's interesting. Do prosecutors keep saying it till reaching to 'long time'? I can understand the example 'an experience they will long remember', meaning they will remember for a long time. But I am not sure how I should understand 'have said it for a long time'. I can understand 'have said it a long time ago'. another eg is 'He has been waiting for a long time', because 'waiting' can last. Any thoughts?

Comment: The prosecutors have been saying it for a long time (starting a long time ago and continuing until now). Here *’to say that ...’* means *’to hold an opinion that ...’* and not to literally speak the words.